# ExtJS 3. Ext.tree.TreeNode OnIconClick events

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, dom-events

I have Ext.tree.TreePanel with many treenodes. I need something like oniconclick event for few of my nodes. I want to use it for three-state checked treenodes.

```
 var node0121 = new Ext.tree.TreeNode({
        id: "0121",
        icon: "/pls_help.png",
        checked: true
    });
```

I tried something like

```
node0121.query('img')[0].on("click",function(){alert("t")});
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
Ext.fly(node0121.getUI().getIconEl()).on('click', function() { 
    alert('t');
});
```